# having a global object with cluster module of node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, resources, express

I am using clustering in the Rest api app built on express in node.js.

the full code for Rest API utilizing clustering is.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var counter = {"color":{},"weight":{}};

if (cluster.isMaster) {

        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
            cluster.fork();
        }

        cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {         
            var exitCode = worker.process.exitCode;
            console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died ('+exitCode+'). restarting...');
            cluster.fork();     
        });



} else {    

        var express = require("express"),
        var msg;
        var server = express();     
        server.use(express.bodyParser());
        server.post('/grouper', function (req, res) {

            //some update on global counter         

        });

        server.listen(8080);

}
```

My question is is there any way i could have a global object just like the counter object shown in code between the different forked instances so that all the instances update the same object?

Comment: The way you can share is 'message' system between processes, or some other messaging protocols, like ZeroMQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All worker processes are indeed new copies of your application variables independently.

Each worker is a full featured process created with [`child_process.fork`](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works). In documents you can get following statement:

> No shared state between the workers. Because workers are all separate
>   processes, they can be killed or re-spawned depending on your
>   program's needs, without affecting other workers

So answer is no you cannot share a variable `counter`, Your cluster processes don't share variables among themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I did this via moving the shared resource update part to the Master like

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {

        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {

            var worker = cluster.fork();

            worker.on('message', function(msg) {

                //update counter according to attributes in msg         
                console.log(counter);

            });


        }

        // some code



} else {    

        var express = require("express"),
        var msg;
        var server = express();     
        server.use(express.bodyParser());
        server.post('/grouper', function (req, res) {

            //some update on global counter  
            msg = req.body;
            //communicate to master here
            process.send(msg);       

        });

        server.listen(8080);

}
```

`process.send` to communicate from child processes to master and keep updation part at master.